# How to read a excel file without taking its first row as header ? Pandas, Python

Tags: python, pandas

The excel

```
  A      B      C   
1 apple  tometo grape
2 beer   wine   juice
```

Reading by pandas, the first row will be the columns of DataFrame.

```
  apple  tometo grape
0 beer   wine   juice
```

How can I read the excel like this:

```
  0      1      2
0 apple  tometo grape
1 beer   wine   juice
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file can be read using the file name as string or an open file object:

```
pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', index_col=0)
```

if you want to read particular sheet.

```
pd.read_excel(open('test.xlsx', 'rb'),sheet_name='Sheet3')
```

Index and header can be specified via the index_col and header arguments

```
pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', index_col=None, header=None)
```

Comment: Hey Jay, ```pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', index_col=None, header=None)``` solved my question, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First answer on google when you search for "pandas read excel file skip header": Pandas doc for method [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) which has a `skiprows` argument to achieve what you like

Since your excel file has no header row, you should use `header=None`

Comment: Hey Emrah, thanks for helping. I've tried it already, ```skiprows```  just omit row, what I want is having a new row as the label of each col.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood what you were asking, I updated my answer